# Cronjob error - mysqldump command not found

Tags: mysql, cron

I am trying to shedule a cronjob that will export my database and put it into a file on the server... but somehow it doesn't do the work... checked the command but it looks ok... i get this error send to my email: mysqldump command not found... here is the command :

```
mysqldump -h localhost -u user_me --password="pas" user_t > /home/me/backup.sql
```

any idea what the problem is? I tryed adding the path to /usr/local/bin/mysqldump instead just the command name but still no luck...

Comment: oh and when i add the path i just get "folder or file not found"

Comment: did you try running this command manually from shell? just to confirm paths

Comment: yeah, i did... i get the sam error just then it says folder or file is not found in that shell script :(

Comment: oh and I tryed this: whereis mysqldump > /home/me/path.txt but i only get "mysqldump: " :(

Comment: that means mysqldump is not where you are looking. Try running a search just to confirm where it is located

Comment: can you give me info on how to do that

Comment: I think `mysqldump` may be not in `PATH` .